# Android studio ssd

Tags: android-studio, ssd

Поделитесь опытом.
Есть система с двумя дисками ssd и hdd.
Какие части Android Studio лучше вынести на hdd?
Пока есть идея вынести папки проектов и git на hdd. Какие части студии могут провоцировать множество циклов перезаписи?

Comment: лучше перенести все части студии на SSD и еще исключить все связанное с разработкой из сканирования антивирусом, особенно исходники проекта, там большое количество мелких файлов. То же касается и системы сборки Gradle

Comment: Для чего вам ссд, если вы не хотите пользоваться его преимуществами? Не надо ничего никуда выносить. Вы другие компоненты компьютера поменяете раньше, чем тот ссд износится.